# Android Studio 4 Complete Offline Setup

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to setup Android Studio For Offline builds, using latest gradle.

## System - Windows 10 64 Bit.

What i have done so far?

1. Downloaded and Installed Android Studio 4.0.1 Windows 64 Bit from official website. Android SDK and AVD also selected during installation. (Internet Install)
2. Downloaded Offline components.

- Android Gradle Plugin.
- Google Maven Dependencies.
  From -https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads

And setup according to docs for offline setup.

3. Downloaded Latest Complete Gradle zip file from :
   https://gradle.org/releases.

- Gradle version 6.5.1 (gradle-6.5.1-all.zip)
  Pasted Gradle zip into .gradle/wrapper/dists/
  And extracted it their.
  And changed the path From File-> Settings->Build Tools->Gradle to above extracted folder.

When i tried to build, i got following errors:

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 Searched in the following locations: - file:/C:/Users/Xevns/.android/manual-offline-m2/gmaven_stable/.../gradle-4.0.1.pom

Once inspected the offline components achieve, i think it uses Old Android Gradle plugin v3.5.0 beta and Old maven dependecy. But in project its using Gradle plugin 4.0.1 and Gradle 6.5.1.

Please help, where find it latest and setup.

Answer (score 0):

1. The so called: latest versions of the Android Gradle plugin link does not contain the latest version. You have to select one that is in that package:
   Grandle Scripts -> build.grandle :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
```

2. The Android Grandle Plugin package does not contain library versions that are needed for that "tools.build:grandle" version - (download manualy from repos?)
3. Other dependencies (appcompat,constraint-layout, ...) the same problem, requested versions are not included in downloaded Google Maven package.